# Arch & Windows 7 dual boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, multi-boot, grub, arch-linux

I installed windows 7 then arch in virtualbox.
When I finished arch installation, windows 7 did not show in grub.

So I thought maybe the boot file of windows are corrupted/missing. I ran the windows 7 iso and repaired mbr and boot files using windows prompt.

At this point, I was able to boot on Windows but not on arch (grub did not appear when booting, directly windows boot).

So I booted on ubuntu live and did a boot-repair, but it did not work.

Then I booted on arch live, arch-chrooted in my arch install and re-installed grub, and mkconfig.

And now I'm back where I was in the first place : I can access to arch grub but cannot chose windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu OS prober found windows. But I couldnt update from there cause of a strange error :

> failed to get-canonical path of /cow

So I used that method : https://askubuntu.com/a/629733 which seems to work for my issue.
Just be careful with the custom grub entry parameters and read the doc if you want to fix a similar issue the same way.